# Can i export a jmeter test as a script?

Tags: testing, automation, html, jmeter

I am trying to build a test framework for front end and back end services. One of the test I want to do is if a certain webpage loads well. I have made a simple test in jmeter, and now my question is: Can i export a script that will run this test on command without having to manually open jmeter?

The idea is that i will be able to go on a webpage and see the results from there. But also i want to be able to run the test when i want to remotely (obviously the back end server will trigger the script on http request)..

So is it possible to export a jmeter test script? if not, is there another tool that can do this?

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:

Ok, i think i found what i was looking for.. and in case anyone else needs something like this check out this link: http://www.programmerplanet.org/pages/projects/jmeter-ant-task.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, as soon as you have saved your test, you can start JMeter in many different ways - from Ant, from Maven, through a shell script, from continuous integration servers and so on.